# "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I've seen this question asked a lot and I know why it happens, I'm just having issues trying to solve it in my specific case.

I'm converting the project I'm working on from using XML files to map classes to database tables for Hibernate, to using Hibernate annotations. Everything is going fine as long as I'm using basic java types (primitives or class versions of primitives, e.g. int or Integer). But when it comes to my class having a member that is another class of mine, things go south.

One type of issue is when I have OnetoMany relationship.

In the XML file for foo it says this:

```
<set inverse="true" name="barList">
    <key>
        <column name="foo_id"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.me.model.dao.Bar" />
</set>
```

In converting this to an annotation, I end up with this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "bar", inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"))
public Set<Bar> getBarList() {
    return barList;
}
```

I've tried other variations of this (including have a JoinColumn), and I know as it stands it may be incomplete, but like I said, I'm having trouble finding a proper solution to get rid of the lazy initial exception when I'm working with the objects in the view of my MVC. FetchType.EAGER is said to be a workaround and not a solution, but curiously, solutions are not offered. Maybe more information is needed.

- My MVC is Wicket 1.4.17.
- My app server is Widlfly (i.e. no web.xml)
- Java version is 8.
- Hibernate, through Maven POM

  - artifact : hibernate
  - version : 3.5.0.ga
  - artifact : ejb3-persistence
  - version : 1.0.1.GA

**Edit:** It might be helpful to add that while barList appears in the foo class, there is no reference of any kind to bar in foo in the database. The foo table does have a bar_id.

Comment: Assuming that you would like to do bidirection one-to-many and many-to-one?! Can we just use annotation for this only?!

Comment: They are already bidirectionally mapped in the XML, but I'm trying to convert one class at a time to annotations. Many of these classes are very complicated with their relationships between complex objects, so I'm trying to do it little by little to track and fix errors more easily. Temporary mixed XML / Annotations seems to be ok for the moment for simpler relationships - will it be ok for bidirectional mapping until i get the one class working and can start on converting the other?

Comment: You have to post something about your Session/Transaction handling. Maybe the problem is that the session to do the lazy loading is gone as soon as you get the Entity from your Repository. (Had this problem with spring-webflow, forgot the <PersistenceContext>-tag)

Comment: @Turo In Java where Hibernate is set up and used, it does HibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession() (if session is null or not open) and then session.beginTransaction(). Then, operations take place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, annotation help to make the mapping more simple and easily. Both xml or annotation are also the same ideas(to make Hibernate to understand our objects' relationship). In this case, the mapping just simple like:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")  
    private Set<Bar> barList;
```

For the whole detail, this sample looks like the same yours: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Hope this help.

Comment: I think I should mention that while the Bar class has a Set of Foos, the Foo class has a single Bar, and in the database, the Bar table has no mention of Foo whatsoever, but Foo does have a foreign key id to Bar. I think this quirk is part of what's messing me up.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm reading correctly. But in the code I saw in the question is the Foo has a Set<Bar> @OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "bar", inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"))
public Set<Bar> getBarList() {
    return barList;
}.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your transaction management configuration because when you use `FetchType.LAZY` your lazy list not loaded until you call it by its getter method.
So that if you invoke getter method after commit transaction, this exception throws.
Please check your transaction configuration or send that part of code here.